# Using moment.js to process a date in Hebrew

Tags: mysql, momentjs, date-format, date-formatting

I have a date in Hebrew that I'm trying to convert to a MySQL-compatible date format using the moment.js library.

A sample date is:
רביעי, 05 אוגוסט 2015 16:50

From **right to left**, the information is: 
Day of the week,
Calendar day,
Month,
Year,
Hours and minutes timestamp

I have tried various things, such as:
moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('LLLL')

But I couldn't get it right with the different variations. The format I would like to get is:
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks,

Maor

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM is not an acceptable format. Use YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. Happy Hanukah

Answer (score 5):

With the help of some colleagues, I now have the answer:

moment(date, 'LLLL', 'he').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

Comment: I must have misunderstood. You appeared to indicate that you wanted to store the data under a MySQL date/time data type.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I do - eventually. I wanted to first convert the date into a compatible format before pushing it into the database. Thanks!